# how to add an ID to a model object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a to do list and my model class is a subclass of NSManagedObject called Targets.

One of my attributes is "targetID" of type NSNumber:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * targetID;
```

I want to give each of this class object an ID..

How should I approach this?

I know it's probably a simple task for most of you but it's the first time im doing this.

I have a view controller that called CreatePageViewController that have a text view sub view, and another ListTableViewController which present all of them...

Where, when and how I give ID to each Target object?

Comment: ID is a reserve word. You could use "anythingID" or iDAnything". But not id.

Comment: Look back and see I gave it the name targetID, how where and when do I use it to give each object an id? Tnx

Comment: Well, when you create a new NSManagedObject, you add this value. I´m going to write the code in a answer.

Comment: Just to make sure: you're aware that managed objects intently have a unique ID; you want to bind some other custom ID into your model?

Comment: So using core data whenever i create an object it gets an id i can use later? To be honest i didnt know but someone told me i should have an id for each todo..@Tommy

Comment: In Core Data, you don´t need an id. Sometimes you use a resourceID because your objects come form a web data base (SQL or not MongoDB, Cas..) and It´s the best way to ask for this register. But In Core Data you can fetch your objects, in function its attributes. I expand my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the other answers; in Core Data you'd normally add an ID field only if you wanted to be able to correlate local data with remote data. You wouldn't add one just for local use.

That's at least partly because Core Data already gifts every object with its own unique ID. You can access the `objectID` property on any managed object to get at it. It's of the [`NSManagedObjectID`](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectID_Class/index.html) opaque type but you can ask for it as a regular URI via `URIRepresenation`, and of course any `NSURL` can be stored as a string.

Starting from an object ID you can use `NSManagedObjectContext`'s [`-existingObjectWithID:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/existingObjectWithID:error:) to get at the actual managed object. If all you have is the URL then you can ask your `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to map that to an object ID via [`-managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator/managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:).

IDs are guaranteed unique but will be in their final form only once the context has been saved or if you've explicitly asked your context to [`-obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:).

`NSFetchRequest` also has a special feature whereby if you do a query for `self in <a collection of NSManagedObjectIDs>` the query actually returns the managed objects rather than the object IDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSManagedObject *newTarget = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Targets" inManagedObjectContext:yourManagedObjectContext];
[newTarget setValue:@25 forKey:@"targetID"];
// we must handle errors, but...
[yourManagedObjectContext save:nil];
```

Fetching Objects. Imagine your Target objects have this attributes:
kindOfTaks : NSString.
endDate : NSTimeInterval (Double).
And now I´m going to see my Personal taks, that I only have 12houres to finish. Ordered.

```
     NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Targegts" inManagedObjectContext:yourManagedObjectContext]];
NSTimeInterval now = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] ;
NSTimeInterval limit = now + 12*3600;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kindOfTaks ='personel' & endDate > %f & endDate < %f",now,limit];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"endDate" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorts = @[sort];
[request setSortDescriptors:sorts];
// Here the results and ordered array:
NSArray *objects = [yourManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explained your solution a bit.